# Placement of Stripe.js file?

Tags: cordova, stripe-payments

I have a Cordova iOS and Android app where I’m including a stripe Elements web form. Where does the...

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

... get placed? Should it go in my Cordova index file? Or should it go into the index file of my hosted web app?

Answer (score 1):

It needs to go (and be loaded) on/with whatever 'page' will have the Elements elements.  I'm not really familiar enough with Cordova to be able to provide a more specific example; sorry.